# Mockito and jdbc procedure call

Tags: jdbc, junit, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test for some jdbc procedure calls with mockito.
It is my first time to write tests with mock objects (mockito).

The method i am trying to test looks some thing like this...

```
 public void deleteData(final Connection connection, final AnObject ) {
     CallableStatement statement = null;

     statement = connection.prepareCall("{call DEL_DATA(?)}");
     statement.setInt(1, object.getId());

     statement.executeUpdate();

     connection.commit();

     DatabaseSql.close(statement);
}
```

How can I test methods like this with mockito and junit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to test? Because I don't thing that you can test anything in this code.

Answer (score 6):

A method like this isn't really a candidate for unit testing, because its whole purpose is to interact with the database.  Maybe you want to test that you're interacting with the database correctly.  This would be a valid test, but to do that, there would need to be a database involved.

Basically, we're talking about an integration test now, not a unit test.  And I can't see that Mockito would be very much help to you, although JUnit certainly would.

In the past, the way I've tested code like this is with a lightweight in-memory database.  There are a few of these, but the one that I would recommend is H2 (h2database.com).  This is fairly fast and easy to use, once you've got the H2 jar in your path.

You probably want your integration test to do the following.

1. Create a dummy table to record procedure calls,
2. Create a dummy DEL_DATA procedure, which does nothing but record what parameters it was called with in the dummy table
3. Run the method
4. Select from the dummy table, to verify that the procedure was called correctly.

With H2, you can run such tests in "in memory" mode, which means there is no need for any clean-up step at the end of each test.

Comment: Another advantage to running an embedded in-memory database is that it's at least an order of magnitude faster than running with a traditional server/client database setup. Meaning your tests execute much, much faster.

Answer (score 4):

There is no point writing a unit test for this code. Once you mocked DB access parts there is no logic left for you to unit test.

You need to mock your business logic no your persistence code.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply :) I am realy not sure if i have to test it. You mean there is no need or way to test the code ?

Comment: There is no point in "unit" testing the above code. But of-course you can test the code. But then that would be an integration tests, which talks and verifies the data which is written to db. Think about it if you mock the db part of the code is there a logic left for you to test.

Answer (score 0):

Well the short answer is "you can't, that's not what it is designed for".

Besides which, your "deleteData" method is not directly testable and has an invalid signature.

In order to test if your functionality works you would have to first invoke your deleteData method, then attempt to load the deleted data (assuming your DataStore is ACID), and assert that the loaded data does not exist. Which is not a unit test (because it is not isolated).

Either rewrite your persistence in such a way as to be testable (as a unit), or alternatively, test this in an integration test instead of a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mock the JDBC calls - it can be done, but it is too complex and there isnot much value in doing it.   Instead you would Mock the deleteData method to test other methods that call it.

To test deleteData method itself you will need to write an integration test that connects to a real database or an embedded database.